# Angular provide a generic service multiple times

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

i created a generic service which i like to provide multiple times including the generic. I tried the following solutions.

Provide using **useFactory**. This gives me an error because my **GenericRepository** has some **DI** services in the constructor which it now expects me to pass along. I dont know  how.

```
{ 
    provide: USERS_REPOSITORY_TOKEN,
    useFactory: () => (new GenericRepository<ApplicationUser>()) 
}, 
{
    // Provide a few more generic repositories
}
```

Provide using `useClass`. This gives me an error on the `<ApplicationUser>` part: `Value of type 'typeof GenericRepository' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?`

```
{ 
    provide: USERS_REPOSITORY_TOKEN,
    useClass: GenericRepository<ApplicationUser>
},
{
    // Provide a few more generic repositories
}
```

---

I found one solution so far which works around these issues but i think it is quite ugly since i could end up with around 10 provides of my **GenericRepository** and multiple **DI** parameters inside the repository.

```
{
    provide: USERS_REPOSITORY_TOKEN,
    deps: [LoggingService],
    useFactory: (loggingService: LoggingService) => {
        return new GenericRepository<ApplicationUser>(loggingService); 
    }
},
{
    // Provide a few more generic repositories
}
```

Thanks in advance!